# Understanding of Band Inversion in $\rm Bi_2Se_3$ Topological Insulator

Tags: symmetry, crystals, orbitals, topological-insulators, topological-order

I'm currently trying to understand Fig. 2 in this Paper (http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.82.045122) which aims to explain the origin of band inversion in Bi2Se3. I really want to get an understanding of this since it's an important concept in the field of topological insulators but I have several questions regarding the steps before the effect of spin-orbit coupling is considered.

1. In Step 1 they say to consider "the hybridization of Bi orbitals and Se orbitals" which let's me think of Valence Bond Theory. But it seems to me that this can clearly not be meant here since the discussion is held about Bi and Se (which are not typically considered in Valence Bond theory) and additionally, the discussion is restricted to p-orbitals only. Besides that, the energy levels are still degenerate so this can clearly not be a discussion of Valence Bond theory. Right now, my understanding of the first step is that it shows how the outside Se atoms in the unit cell are different from the Se atom in the inversion center. Can this be explained by symmetry only or is this rather a consequence of the different bond schemes? The outermost Se atoms have a double bond to the next Bi atom and have van-der-Waals forces to the next quintuple layer while the innermost Se atom only has two single bonds to the next Bi atoms. Please bear in mind that all this is speculation as a I just entered the topic and am quite confused at the moment, so please correct me if my assumptions are blatantly wrong.

2. In step 2, bonding and antibonding states are defined which only contain the wave functions of the same atom types (see eq. 1 in the paper). This does not make sense to me since the bonding scheme in a Bi2Se3 unit cell should look something like this Se=Bi-Se-Bi'=Se'. So every element forms bonds with the other element. Why are the bonding and antibonding states then defined only in terms of orbitals from the same type of atom?

3. In step 3 the crystal field splitting is considered. From the layered crystal structure, it is immediately apparent that the z orbitals should have different energies than the ones in the xy-plane. The part which confuses me is that with the same argument, the energy splitting is supposed to have opposite "directions" regarding Bi and Se. So why is the energy within the Bi xy-plane higher than along z while the xy-states have lower energy in the Se layers?

EDIT: I was told that the majority of my confusion might have to do with the tight binding / LCAO approach. Even after reading up on that, my confusion unfortunately remains.

Comment: I haven't read [this](https://doi.org/10.1063/5.0022525), but maybe it would help.